# can not connect to postgres db from node server

Tags: node.js, linux, postgresql

I want to connect my apps nodejs using node-posgres to PostgreSQL. My apps in linux server and my postgresql in another linux server by  176.9.154.123 IP.

this is my error:

[image]

this is my pg_hba.conf:

```
host    all             all             176.9.154.123/32        trust
```

Comment: Firewalling? Connection Setup? Hard to tell with that little info. Bump up log verbosity on the postgres  box ...

Comment: It's better to post error messages as text, not screenshots (the way you did with `pg_hba.conf`)

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. Please don't use links to images. The text is missing from the question. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors. Also see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can solve this problem by add this line to postgressql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```